¿Como poner AutoScroll en un Form pero solo en vertical?
Le quiero poner la propiedad AutoScroll a una app WinForm, pero cuando lo hago, si o si se le activan tanto el horizontal como el vertical.
Quisiera poder evitar por completo el horizontal y activar solo el autoscroll vetical.
¿Alguien sabe si se puede hacer y como?


Podrías colocar el código para tener mejor contexto del problema.

@FernandoCarraro dificil que ponga el codigo, porque es winforms y eso se activa mediante propiedades del form....
